# Как прекратить игру "Жизнь" при зацикливании?

Tags: c, алгоритм, циклические-зависимости

Как прекратить игру при зацикливании? Можно, конечно, с самой первой матрицей элементов, сравнивать каждую, и на моменте, когда все элементы совпадут (сделать какойнить счетчик), завершить. Но вот не знаю, могут ли быть такие случаи, когда самая первая "жизнь" не будет частью зацикливания.

Comment: Обычно самая первая как раз не будет частью зацикливания. Сравнивать следует с состоянием, которое было на итерации, кратной N.

Comment: А что такое эта N?

Comment: N - Это максимальная длина цикла, который планируется обнаружить.

Answer (score 2):

Хороший поиск циклов работает с двумя играми начиная от **одной** позиции. Первая игра со стандартной скоростью, вторая игра будет в два раза быстрее *(два хода)*. При выполнении трёх ходов : один стандартный и два ускоренных сравниваются карты на равенство. Если они совпадают, значит полный цикл присутствует между картами со стандартной и быстрой скоростью.

Наглядно демонстрирую карты буквами :

```
xyzabcabc...
```

стандарт   быстро

```
x       x  y
y       z  a
z       b  c
a       a  b
b       c  a
c       b  c
```

Всё `c == c` .

Comment: То есть мне надо дублировать все функции что ли...

Comment: Если в вашей проге один ход выполняет одна функция, то так : `map a,b; do{ hod(a); hod(b); hod(b); } while( mapnoteq(a , b));` не так и сложно.

Comment: Так я тут немного подумал. Вот эта игра "жизнь". Допустим есть 2 фигуры на поле, одна зацикливается, вторая через пару ходов умрет. Но поля совпадут в момент, когда зацикливающаяся фигура была на старте, хотя по идее зацикливание еще не началось, так как цикл назад в этот момент еще была жива вторая фигура.

Comment: карту вы сравниваете **полностью** и зафиксируется цикл только **после** смерти второй фигуры.